# Should media query be placed alongside the class or all at the end of SCSS file?

Tags: html, css, sass

Imagine I have a SCSS file with some media queries, there are 2 options to place the media queries:

option 1: place media queries alongside the class,

```css
.widget {
  width: 100px;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    width: 10px;
  }
  .widget-header {
    height: 50px;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      height: 20px;
    }
    .close-button {
      display: block;
      @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

option 2: place all media queries after the normal classes,

```css
.widget {
  width: 100px;
  .widget-header {
    height: 50px;
    .close-button {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .widget {
    width: 10px;
    .widget-header {
      height: 20px;
      .close-button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

I can see they both have pros and cons, like option 1 keeps all media queries close to the original classes so it's easy to find them, but it needs to repeat `@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)`, looks messy, and if developer wants to change the max-width he/she would have to go through each class to change them. Option 2 keeps all media query in 1 place, looks neat, if wants to change max-width just needs to change once. However option 2 has to repeat the HTML structure.

What's the recommended way of placing the media queries?

Comment: For me it's just a stylistic choice. Personally, if I need to change "large piece of code" (like the whole class) I prefer option 2, if it's just a single line I go for 1.

Regarding the change of many media query I would recommend to use a mixin.

Comment: @alula I have changed the codebase to option 2, I think it's a better choice especially if you want to change the media query width, with option 1 it's just impossible if the code is big.